# What are the things possible inside procedure example we can call sql query inside the procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_name(p_a IN Number)
AS

BEGIN

END proc_name;
/

Comment: There can be SQL in the procedure, but there doesn't have to be. You could write a [CSV output generator](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml), or a [Sudoku solver](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/sudoku-solver.shtml). What do you want to do?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, quite a lot of things are possible! Here's just one example:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure proc_name(p_a in number) as
  2    l_value number;
  3  begin
  4    select count(*) into l_value      --> here's your query in the procedure
  5    from emp
  6    where deptno = p_a;
  7
  8    dbms_output.put_line('Number of employees in dept. ' || p_a || ' is '|| l_value);
  9  end proc_name;
 10  /

Procedure created.
```

How does it work?

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    proc_name(10);
  3  end;
  4  /
Number of employees in dept. 10 is 3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

If that's not what you wanted, perhaps you should explain the problem a little bit better.